# Solving differential equation using Fourier

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I'd like to solve the following equation using Fourier
$$
y(t)+ {\sqrt 2\over 2\pi5} {dy(t)\over dt}+({1\over2\pi5})^2 {d^2y(t)\over dt^2}=x(t)
$$
where $x(t) = u(t)$ (step function)
So far i've got
$$
Y(f)+{\sqrt 2j2\pi f\over 2\pi 5}Y(f)+({j2\pi f\over2\pi5})^2Y(f)=X(f)
$$
$$
Y(f)=X(f)+5\sqrt 2 \pi {1\over j2\pi f}X(f)+{25\over -f^2}X(f)
$$
$$
y(t)=x(t)+5\sqrt 2 \pi {\int x(t)dt} +...
$$
I'm kinda stuck can you help me? (i'm not even sure if it's correct so far...) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider the following PDE$$a\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}\left(t\right)+b\frac{dy}{dt}\left(t\right)+cy\left(t\right)=u\left(t\right).$$
 One formally applies the Fourier transform$$\hat{y}\left(\omega\right)=TF\left[y\right]\left(\omega\right)=\intop y\left(t\right)e^{-i\omega t}dt$$
 and obtains$$-a\omega^{2}\hat{y}\left(\omega\right)+ib\omega\hat{y}\left(\omega\right)+c\hat{y}\left(\omega\right)=\hat{u}\left(\omega\right)$$
 i.e.$$\hat{y}\left(\omega\right)=\frac{\hat{u}\left(\omega\right)}{-a\omega^{2}+ib\omega+c}.$$
 Now using the convolution formula, one gets$$y\left(t\right)=\left(TF^{-1}\left[\omega\mapsto\frac{1}{-a\omega^{2}+ib\omega+c}\right]*TF^{-1}\left[\hat{u}\right]\right)\left(t\right).$$
 To compute $F^{-1}\left[\omega\mapsto\frac{1}{-a\omega^{2}+ib\omega+c}\right]$
 , one can use the residue formula :$$TF^{-1}\left[\omega\mapsto\frac{1}{-a\omega^{2}+ib\omega+c}\right]\left(t\right)$$ $$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\intop\frac{e^{i\omega t}}{-a\omega^{2}+ib\omega+c}d\omega
 =\frac{1}{2\pi}\intop\frac{e^{i\omega t}}{-a\left(\omega-\omega_{-}\right)\left(\omega-\omega_{+}\right)}d\omega$$
 where $\omega_{\pm}=\frac{-ib\pm\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}{2a}.$
 One obtains$$TF^{-1}\left[\omega\mapsto\frac{1}{-a\omega^{2}+ib\omega+c}\right]=i\frac{e^{-\frac{b}{2a}t-i\frac{\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}{2a}t}}{\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}-i\frac{e^{-\frac{b}{2a}t+i\frac{\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}{2a}t}}{\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}=\frac{2e^{-\frac{b}{2a}t}}{\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}{2a}t\right).$$
  I think I made no mistake, but you may check it. Verify also that all the above calcula are allowed (why the complex contour integral converges ?). I also let you evaluate $\hat{u}\left(\omega\right)
 .$

Comment: Thanks, very helpfull but I'm having troubles with the residue formula, can you give me more details if it isn't too much troubles?

Comment: Edit : some mistakes  (of course!...), fixed.
The residue formula states that the integral value is $2\pi i\sum_{k}\mathrm{Res}\left(f;z_{k}\right)$ where $f$ is the function that you integrate (it is actually the extension of $f$ in the complex plane) and the $z_{k}$ are the poles of $f$.
Here, all the two poles are simple, then the residue at $\omega_{+}$ for example is the function $\left(\omega-\omega_{+}\right)f\left(\omega_{+}\right)$, and idem for the other pole $\omega_{-}$.
A last thing here : since there is the Heavyside step function in your problem, $t$ is actually non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$Y(f)+C_1   fY(f)+C_2f^2Y(f)=X(f),$$ where $C_i$ are (eventually) complex constants. Their exact form depend on your conventions for Fourier transform.

Hence,
$$Y(f) = \frac{X(f)}{1+C_1f+C_2f^2}.$$
Now you can take the inverse Fourier transform of both sides to reconstruct $y(t)$. As you can guess, Fourier transform for solving linear ODE's is largely non-optimal (except for carefully tailored examples).

Comment: Yeah it is a tailored example